# DiracDelta not giving correct result

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-integration

I have to use dirac delta in a complicated integral and was hoping to see how it works with a simple case but it returns the wrong answer. Any clue what I did wrong in the following?

```
from sympy import DiracDelta
from scipy import integrate

def f(x):
     return x*DiracDelta(x-1)

b, err = integrate.quad(f, 0, 5)    
print b
```

This returns `0.0` while it shouldn't.

Comment: Agreed, the answer should be one, the area under the delta function being zero and concentrated around x=1 , where the multipler x is not changing anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems `sympy` functions are not compatible with `scipy` integrate. One needs to use `sympy` integrate. The following gives the correct answer

```
from sympy import *
x = Symbol('x')
print integrate(x*DiracDelta(x-1), (x, 0, 5.0))
```

Although, I am not sure if `sympy.integrate` is as powerful and versatile as `scipy.integrate`.

Comment: **Symbolic** integration (done by sympy) and **numeric** integration (done by scipy) are very different things. Sticking an abstract object like DiracDelta into a numeric integration routine is like sticking fingers into a power outlet; the thing just doesn't belong there.

Comment: Ah, beat me to it.  Basically, scipy's integration is a *numerical* integration, and doesn't play nicely with sympy in general, even more so when we have something as peculiar as the delta "function".

Comment: @DSM Your answer was better, please undelete.

Answer (score 2):

HuShu's answer is correct. I'll add that the Dirac δ function is a symbolic method of representing function evaluation as an integral. It's useful as a symbolic abstraction, but if you only care about numeric evaluation, just do the function evaluation. That is instead of

```
b
⌠
⎮ f(x)⋅DiracDelta(x - 1) dx
⌡
a
```

just use

```
f(1) if a <= 1 <= b else 0
```